# How can I extend a memory of an analysed executable in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, disassembly, malware, anti-debugging, immunity-debugger

I'm analysing some malware executable with ImmDBG and IDA Pro.

The executable calls the *kernel32.VirtualAlloc()* at runtime with an argument *lpAddress=NULL* what means that an operating system decides itself where the memory has to be allocated. The *VirtualAlloc()* returns an address 0x003F0000. After that the executable writes some function to this memory, which is quite big, and I would like to analyse this function in IDA Pro.

The problem is, that my executable is loaded to the 0x004010000 in IDA Pro
and I don't know how could I extend the memory of the executable in IDA Pro in order to create this function manually(with help of PatchBytes).

Also maybe it's possible somehow to build a function from a sequence of opcodes in IDA Pro?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try running it using the IDA debugger? It allows you to take snapshots of the memory and keep them inside the IDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a new section in IDA Pro (**File -> Segments -> Create segment**). After that I dumped new section in OllyDBG (binary copy) and transferred it to the new created section in IDA Pro (with a Python script). After that I could analyse the code and write comments in IDA to make better analysis and documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable solution I've found is to add a new section to the PE file and force the process to write the unpacked code into that new section in memory.

I wrote up a blog post a few years ago with a full walk-through of this approach: http://blog.crowdstrike.com/unpacking-dynamically-allocated-code/

[image: Screenshot]